# General Solution of IVPs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to obtain the general solution the IVP(INTIAL VALUE PROBLEM)

$$ y'=y^2-\frac{y}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}$$ ;${x}>0$  ;     $y_1$($x)=\frac{1}{x}$    ;  $y(1)=2$.

Where $y_1(x)$ denotes a solution to the differential equation.

But was clealry stuck since I couldn't apply bernoulli or normal principles

Anyone with an idea to go by it...

Comment: by $y_1(x)$ you mean the first derivative of $y$ ?

Comment: Yes thanks for rectification

Comment: I don't get you are trying to say

Comment: I get you now thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the structure for the substitution $u=xy$. Then
$$
\frac{u'}{u^2-1}=\frac1x\implies \frac{u-1}{u+1}=Cx^2\implies u(x)=\frac{1+Cx^2}{1-Cx^2}
$$
so that then finally
$$
y(x)=\frac{1+Cx^2}{x(1-Cx^2)}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$y'=y^2-\frac{y}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}$$
This is [Riccati's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation).

Substitute $y=u+\dfrac 1x$ since $\dfrac 1x$ is a solution:
$$(u+\frac 1x)'=(u+\dfrac 1x)^2-\frac{1}{x}(u+\dfrac 1x)-\frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$u'-\frac{1}{x^2}=(u+\dfrac 1x)^2-\frac{1}{x}(u+\dfrac 1x)-\frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$u'=(u+\dfrac 1x)^2-\frac{1}{x}(u+\dfrac 1x)$$
$$u'=(u+\dfrac 1x)u$$
This is Bernoulli's DE.
$$u'-\dfrac ux=u^2$$
$$xu'-u=xu^2$$
$$\left (\dfrac xu \right)'=-x$$
Integrate:
$$\dfrac xu=-\dfrac {x^2}2+C$$
$$u=\dfrac {2x} {K-x^2}$$
Subsititute back $u=y-\frac 1x$
$$y-\dfrac 1 x =\dfrac {2x} {K-x^2}$$
Apply initial condition ($y(1)=2$)in order to find the value of the constant $K$.
$$y=\dfrac {K+x^2} {x(K-x^2)}$$
You find $K=3$
$$\implies y=\dfrac {3+x^2} {x(3-x^2)}$$

Comment: +1 Brilliant substitution! May I know your thought process behind this sub ?

Comment: Oh I see.. I couldn't think of this because I don't know what Riccati DEs are. Gotta read up on them !